# Character map Utility for Mac?

Tags: mac, software-rec, characters

I want to type some special character like heart, Ohm sign , in Windows, I could be able to copy these from character map easily, is there any utility alike Windows Character map for Mac ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find details about the Character Palette at [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1518) from the Mac support site. The procedure is a bit different depending on your version of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a small flag in the top right corner of your menu bar, click this and a character map menu will appear - from here you can get an interactive character map that changes when you press down certain operator keys (e.g. apple/ alt etc.); or a character map.

If this flag doesn't seem to be there - check out system preferences, and the click the "international" icon, you should be able to check a box to incorporate the flag in your menu bar from here.

Answer (score 1):

The Character Palette as mentioned by Gnoupi is IMO the best solution.

But if you prefer a standalone program, the UnicodeChecker might be a solution as well (you can copy&paste the characters from the UnicodeChecker into your program):

http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/